# LP relaxation in SCIP

Tags: linear-programming, glpk, integer-programming, scip

I'm trying to solve a MIP using the SCIP command line, with the problem input in CPLEX LP format. However, due to large number of variables, the optimization is taking a lot of time. Is there some way to compute the LP Relaxtion solution of the same MIP in SCIP?

Or any other way to get an approximate, somewhat suboptimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just interested in the LP relaxation you should try to use [SoPlex](http://soplex.zib.de) to solve your problem.
If you want to limit the computation time in SCIP you can set a node limit, a solution limit, an objective limit, a time limit or a combination of these. You can find these settings in `set/limits/` in the interactive shell