# How to solve the linear relaxation of a PySCIPOpt Model

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, scip

Given a `pyscipopt.Model`, how to solve its linear relaxation in the shortest code possible?

The documentation is hard to navigate. There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709905/lp-relaxation-in-scip) before, but the answer does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through all variables and change their types to `CONTINUOUS`:

```
for v in model.getVars():
    m.chgVarType(v, 'CONTINUOUS')
```

Then you can solve the LP relaxation of the problem. Please note that your model should be a standard MIP and not contain any nonlinear or general constraints.